# What is the equivalent/alternate to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR in db2 for iSeries platform?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=plsql-raise-application-error

I'm getting the following exception in java when my plslq function code uses the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR to throw an error to the caller

> [[SQL0204] RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR in *LIBL type *N not found.]

Note:
My code works fine in Db2 for Windows(DB2 LUW)

Expecting an alternate way to implement the custom application error handling.

Comment: It is normal for syntax to differ between Db2 platforms (LUW versus i-series).  Only use the __correct__ documentation for your target Db2-server platform.  Why not use the SIGNAL statement for i-series, refer to documentation for i series at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=statements-signal

Comment: RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR works in DB2LUW because Oracle compatibility has been activated. There's not such thing on IBM i, [RAISE_ERROR](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=functions-raise-error) is available in both DB2LUW and DB2forI